# Integral form of conservation law and derivation of the 1D law in JW Thomas

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm reading *Numerical Partial Differential Equations: Conservation Laws and Elliptic Equations* by JW Thomas, and the introduction of Chapter 9 has me confused. The author writes

> We consider the numerical solution of partial differential equations of the form
> \begin{align}
>    \hspace{2cm}  \frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{v}) = \theta  \hspace{2cm} (9.1.1)
> \end{align}
> where $\mathbf{v}$ is a $K$-vector and $F$ is a function that maps $\mathbb{R}^{K}$ into $\mathbb{R}^K$. Unless we specifically state otherwise, we will assume that $\mathbf{F}''(v) \geq 0$, i.e., that $\mathbf{F}$ is convex. An equation of the form (9.1.1) is said to be in **conservation form** and is called a **conservation law**. If we integrate (9.1.1) with respect to $x$ and $t$ and $a$ to $b$ and $t_1$ to $t_2$, respectively, and perform the integration with respect to $t$ for the first term and with respect to $x$ for the second term, we obtain
> $$ \hspace{0cm} \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{v}(x,t_2)\,dx - \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{v}(x,t_1)\,dx = - \left( \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{v}(b,t))\,dt - \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{v}(a,t))\,dt \right) \hspace{2cm} (9.1.2) $$

**Question 1**: Why does $\mathbf{\theta}$ not appear in the above equation? It seems to me that we should have
\begin{align*}
   \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{v}(x,t_2)\,dx - \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{v}(x,t_1) \,dx &= - \left( \int_{t_1}^{t_2} F(\mathbf{v}(b,t))\,dt - \int_{t_1}^{t_2} F(\mathbf{v}(a,t))\,dt \right) \\[5pt]
  & \quad + \int_{a}^{b} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \theta(x,t)\,dt\,dx
\end{align*}

On the next page, the author derives the 1-dimensional conservation law
$$ \hspace{5cm} v_t + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} F(v) = 0 \hspace{5cm} (9.2.1) $$

> The derivation of a conservation law generally begins by considering the amount of substance in an arbitrary interval $[x_0,x_1]$, $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} v(x,t)\,dx$. The conservation law then states that the rate of change of this substance is equal to the flux of substance across the boundaries (plus any of the substance that is created or destroyed in the regions, but since we are interested in homogeneous equations, we will ignore this contribution)

$$ \hspace{4cm} \frac{d}{dt} \int_{x_0}^{x_1} v(x,t)\,dx = [F]_{x_0}^{x_1} \hspace{4cm} (9.2.2) $$

> where for now, $F$ is vaguely defined to be the flux function. Interchanging the differentiation and integration on the left hand side of equation (9.2.2) and writing the right hand side as an interval gives
> $$ \int_{x_0}^{x_1} (v_t - F_x)\,dx = 0. $$
> Then, using the fact that the interval $[x_0,x_1]$ is arbitrary and that the function $v_t - F_x$ is smooth, we obtain (9.2.1).

**Question 2:** Shouldn't the last equation really be $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} (v_t + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} F(v)) \,dx$, and shouldn't the right hand side of (9.2.2) really be $-[F(v(x,t))]_{x_0}^{x_1}$?

I just want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Weirdly enough, he uses boldface $\theta$ to denote the zero vector. (It's explained just below (8.2.67) on page 26.)

Q2. You're right.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! That is indeed a strange notation for the zero vector...